# Django Rest Framework - "detail": "Not found."

Tags: json, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, mixins

Hi when doing this request: groups/25010a31-fc5b-47c8-9c5c-d740e5743f52/members/4/ - I get "detail": "Not found"

However, if you look in the queryset I have printed the Groupmember instance and this ends up printing out that particular instance so clearly it exists?

View:

```
class MemberDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupMembersSerializer
    lookup_field = "user_id"
    lookup_url_kwarg = "uuid"

    def get_queryset(self):
        group = self.kwargs["uuid"]
        user_id = self.kwargs["user_id"]
        print GroupMember.objects.get(group = group, user_id = user_id)
        return GroupMember.objects.get(group = group, user_id = user_id)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls:

```
 urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.GroupList.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[^/]+)/$', views.GroupDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[^/]+)/members/$', views.MemberList.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[^/]+)/members/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.MemberDetail.as_view()),

]
```

Any help?

Comment: There is one thing I see right away: your `get_queryset` returns a single object instead of a queryset. I think you've meant `filter` instead of `get`.

Comment: @Ivan `Filter` results with the same issue

Comment: Please post your urls.

Comment: @RahulGupta urls added

Comment: @Danny this was not a complete answer, I just pointed out an error.

Comment: @Danny This is really weird -- none of your urls includes `"group"` (usually it's something like `r'^group/(?P<uuid>[^/]+)`). Normally router would look for `"group-detail"` and would not find one. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ivan This is what the urlpatterns in the urls.py in the project folder: `url(r'^api/v1/groups/', include('groups.urls')),` - it seemed a bit silly having /groups/group/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, you need to return a queryset in `get_queryset()` method.

Also, you have incorrectly defined `lookup_url_kwarg` as `uuid`. It should infact be `user_id` as this url `kwarg` value is used to perform lookup for `uuid` `lookup_field` in the queryset returned from the `get_queryset()` method.

The default value for `lookup_url_kwarg` if unset is the same value as `lookup_field`. So, we don't need to define `lookup_url_kwarg` even. It will be computed from `lookup_field`.

```
class MemberDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupMembersSerializer
    lookup_field = "user_id" # no need to define 'lookup_url_kwarg' as both have same value

    def get_queryset(self):
        group = self.kwargs["uuid"]
        return GroupMember.objects.filter(group = group) # return a queryset
```

In the `get_queryset()` method, we just filter using the `group` and not by `user_id` as this will be performed by DRF itself whenever there is a `retrieve` request.

Using `.get()` on a queryset will return an object and not a queryset. To perform filtering based on the value of `lookup_field`, we need a queryset. Now, `.filter()` returns a queryset so we used that here.

**Note:** When you returned `GroupMember.objects.filter(group = group, user_id = user_id)`, the `retrieve` tried to perform lookup on this returned queryset on the `user_id` field with its value as `lookup_url_kwarg` value i.e. `user_id=25010a31-fc5b-47c8-9c5c-d740e5743f52`. Since no such object exists in that queryset, it returned that error.

Comment: @RagulGupta Thanks, this worked - could you explain why its `.filter` instead of `.get`

Comment: @Danny Updated the ans.

Comment: @RagulGupta I appreciate it!

Comment: In my case the model field did not have the same name as the url kwarg. In this case you can set them to different values like `lookup_field="model_field_name"` and `lookup_url_kwarg="url_kwarg_name"`

Answer (score 9):

In my case in my routers.py file I had written it like this

```
router.register(r'',PersonViewSet)
router.register(r'PersonEmployee',PersonEmployeeViewSet)
```

so I changed it to

```
router.register(r'PersonEmployee',PersonEmployeeViewSet)
router.register(r'',PersonViewSet)
```

It was reading the empty path URL first and throwing detail not found, so I kept router with the empty path at last and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

normally this error appears when you installed Django rest framework datatables, please check the next values on the configuration of Rest Framework on your settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_datatables.renderers.DatatablesRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework_datatables.filters.DatatablesFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework_datatables.pagination.DatatablesPageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 50,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'utils.rest_framework.views.exception_handler'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add. In the case I was looking at the `queryset` wasn't returning a queryset with the expected object, so in terms of what the changes would look like for your question:

```
class MemberDetail(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupMembersSerializer
    queryset = GroupMember.objects.filter(...)
```

changed to:

```
queryset = GroupMember.objects.all()
```