# Django - multiple fields lookup

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I've an endpoint that accepts either the `uuid` or the `phonenumber` of the user

```
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[0-9A-Fa-f+-]+)/$', view_name.as_view()),
```

Now, I've a queryset that filter accordingly. Here it is.

```
class UserDetails(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Over-riding queryset.

        Filter user based on the user_id(Works for both msisdn & uuid).
        """
        msisdn_or_uuid = self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]
        queryset = Users.objects
        try:  # checking if the forwarded param is user_id or msisdn.
            UUID(msisdn_or_uuid)
            instance = queryset.filter(uuid=msisdn_or_uuid)
        except ValueError:
            instance = queryset.filter(msisdn=msisdn_or_uuid)
            print instance # prints a queryset. But returns 404.
        return instance
```

Now the problem is whenever phone number is passed, it returns 404 not found. But the objects clearly exist.

**Is there any setting in DRF that filters on two or more fields simultaneously without over-riding the `get_queryset`.??**

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373966/django-rest-framework-detail-not-found), but couldn't make it work. Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is what I've tried. It works. But would like to hear better solutions(if any)

```
class FilterByUuidMsisdnMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin to filter by multiple lookup_fields.

    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field (only uuid &
    msisdn) filtering, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """

    def get_object(self):
        """Over-riding get_object."""
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        field = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_field)
        filters = {}
        try:  # checking if the forwarded param is user_id or msisdn.
            UUID(field)
            filters['uuid'] = field  # filter by uuid.
        except ValueError:
            filters['msisdn'] = field  # filter by msisdn.

        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filters)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)  # check permissions.
        return obj
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461366/multiple-lookup-fields-for-django-rest-framework

Comment: You should make two different URLs for this that both point to your view_name. This way you can change the regular expression for each, one to match UUIDs, the other to match Phone numbers.

Comment: It's not this function 404ing then, but `get_queryset_or_404` or something similar. Add a pdb breakpoint and see where the exception is actually being raised.

Comment: @itzMEonTV - This doesn't work. Tried. Still getting 404.

Comment: Did some debugging, it says `keyerror msisdn`

Comment: @bruno - Although duplicate, but still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast do you mean it doesn't solve your problem ? Or that it doesn't answer your question verbatim ?

Comment: @bruno - It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @people- I've updated the question with the answer. Since I didn't had the option to answer the question, kindly review the solution.